# Limit access to specific IPs on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, load-balancer

Out system is based on several IIS servers with ALB and one SQL Server.
On IIS only one site is in use, and it serves our clients, each having their subdomain.
Some of our clients need to limit the access to their subdomain to their IPs.

What is the right way to do it? I know about possibility to build access lists in URLReWrite in IIS, but I prefer to set these limitations outside of my servers.

Your help will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can use an ALB rule based on Source IP that can be limited to specific sites used in conjunction with the host header or path. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-route-requests-with-source-ip-alb/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Security Groups on your ALB. Instead of allowing any IP, you set the list of IPs that are allowed to access your service.

Comment: The problem with security groups is that it applies to all connections, and the OP has indicated “some” clients want to limit the IP addresses.

Comment: Yes, but he can use different ALBs for these specific clients with the corresponding SG. Not sure if I am getting the requirements.

Comment: @Algeriassic I would like to stay with one ALB if possible.

Comment: You can use WAF (Web Application Firewall) with your ALB.

Comment: @Algeriassic Do you have any resource what should I do in WAF to make it work?